# How to show specific range for correlation coefficient in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, correlation

I am importing columns in Excel and finding correlation coefficient between these columns.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('ExcelFileName.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.corr()
```

I need to show only correlation coefficient fitting between +0.6 to +1 and -0.5 to -1.